# What is the best way to check file system capacity using .Net?

Tags: .net, filesystems

What is the best way in .Net to make sure a path as capacity to store a file.  I need to makes sure I have room for the file before I download is becasue the source will not allow the file to be downloaded a second time.  I have looked at System.IO.DriveInfo but this does not work for UNC paths.

Comment: How about an API call instead of WMI?

Comment: @Matthew: Why do you prefer API over WMI? There's an extremely short solution, and by using the WMI you're keeping fully managed (using the System.Management namespace).

Comment: I just think a simple PInvoke would be better than playing in WMI.  But I guess WMI might work.

Comment: @Matthew: I've updated my post so that it now demonstrates two methods (WMI and Win32 API). Though clearly the former is simpler, either should work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a short function taken from [this page](http://www.dev102.com/2008/10/29/how-to-get-free-disk-space-and-other-wmi-stuff-net/) that shows how you can get the free space of any drive (local or network/UNC) using WMI.

```
private static ulong GetFreeDiskSpaceInBytes(string drive)
{
    ManagementObject disk =
        new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"" + drive + ":\"");
    disk.Get();
    return (ulong)disk["FreeSpace"];
}
```

If you wnat a Win32 API solution, you can use the `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` function, as suggested by [this MSDN help page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202455). It too seems to support both local and network drive names.

```
Private Declare Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetDiskFreeSpaceExA" (ByVal lpDirectoryName As String, _
    lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller As Currency, _
    lpTotalNumberOfBytes As Currency, _
    lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes As Currency) As Long

Private Sub Form_Click()
    Dim Status As Long
    Dim TotalBytes As Currency
    Dim FreeBytes As Currency
    Dim BytesAvailableToCaller As Currency

    Status = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(Text1.Text, BytesAvailableToCaller, _
      TotalBytes, FreeBytes)
    If Status <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Format(TotalBytes * 10000, "#,##0"), , "Total Bytes"
        MsgBox Format(FreeBytes * 10000, "#,##0"), , "Free Bytes"
        MsgBox Format(BytesAvailableToCaller * 10000, "#,##0"), , _
          "Bytes Available To Caller"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you're having trouble converting that to C#, let me know.

I would have to recommend the WMI solution here, it being fully managed (aside from fewer lines), but either should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you could get the answers you require using WMI, it is usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The only sure way to see if the disk can store the file is to actually create a file of that size on the disk.

Even if the disk information says that there is room enough, due to defragmentation you can rarely use 100% of the free disk space.

Comment: I was thinking of making sure that that two to three times the spaces that is needed exists just to have extra coverage. But thanks for the note